# RuntimeError: Only tuples, lists and Variables supported as JIT inputs, but got NoneType

Tags: pytorch, onnx

My code is

```
a=torch.randn(1,80,100,requires_grad=True)
torch.onnx.export(waveglow,a, "waveglow.onnx")
```

I am trying to export a PyTorch model to ONNX format so i can use it in TensorRT. while testing my model in PyTorch the input tensor dimension is (1,80,x) where x varies depending on the input text length(the model i am using is TTS model named waveglow)

when i try to run the above code for exporting the model to onnx, I am always getting this error

```
RuntimeError: Only tuples, lists and Variables supported as JIT inputs, but got NoneType
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have NoneType, perhaps you could check if there is an actual input, because the fact is, you actually got `None`.

Also, any reason to not use Variable? Variable converts your inputs to a tensor that can be accepted as an input for `torch.onnx.export`.